# NativeScript tab icons and Badges

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have the following code for my app that I created with NativeScript with Angular 2

```
<TabView>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: '&#xf015; Profile &#xf1e0;" >
   <Label class="fa" text="&#xf015;"></Label>
<Button class="fa" id="button" text="&#xf1e0; Tap me!" ></Button>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: '&#xf015; Stats">
        <Label text="Second tab item"></Label>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Settings'}">
        <Label text="Third tab item"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</TabView>
```

here is am setting the icons for tabTitle as follows

```
   <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: '&#xf015; Profile &#xf1e0;" >
```

I am using fontAwesome but the icons set are simple not shown for the tab title. No placeholder for missing icons is shown either.

Icons do show up for labels and buttons.

Also is there a way I can add badges to tabs as shown in the below image

[image]

This is helpful when there is an update.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the *tabItem does not support icon fonts because of reasons discussed [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/364).
As a workaround, use **iconSource** which allows you to provide images for your tabs.

```
<StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'My Title', iconSource:'res://icon'}">
```

Comment: thanks for the reply..Is there a way to dnamically change the image..I tired to bind the path  *tabItem='{{iconObj.value}}' ... I would like to change the image dynamically as shown above to represent updates to the view.

Answer (score 0):

As @Nick has said, `tabItem` does not support icon fonts at the moment. I also had a trouble like you that I had to implement a tab bar with icons and badges. This is how I did it, and I hope it be useful somehow even though it's not really good practice.

I created a `GridLayout` inside a `DockLayout` set property `dock="bottom"` (fake tabBar). Inside the `GridLayout`, I made a set of labels whose text can be displayed by icon font. I also add a swipe gesture listener so that users can change tab by swiping. That's the idea that might solve the problem temporarily.